# When the condition is in Chinese, The result is empty

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc

```
std::string cmd("select * from _Char where CharName = 'john'"); //SQL_SUCCESS
std::string cmd("select * from _Char where CharName = '你好'"); //SQL_NO_DATA

wchar_t * wcmd = new wchar_t[cmd.size()];
swprintf(wcmd, 100, L"%S", cmd.c_str());

SQLCancel(sqlStmtHandle);

if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLExecDirectW(sqlStmtHandle, wcmd, SQL_NTS))
{
    printf("SQL_SUCCESS");
    return;
}
else
{
    printf("SQL_NO_DATA");
    return;
}
```

When the condition is in Chinese, The result is empty.

Please help me, thank you very much!

```
SQLDriverConnectW(
sqlConnHandle, 
NULL, 
(SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost, 1433;DATABASE=SRO_VT_SHARD;UID=sa;PWD=!su*7G2c(ya!;CHARSET=UTF-8", 
SQL_NTS, 
retconstring, 
1024, 
NULL, 
SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

Comment: Why not directly use `std::wstring`?

Comment: Have you tried `std::string cmd("select * from _Char where CharName = N'你好'");` instead? In SQL Server string literals that start with the `N` character represent [National Character Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) in UCS-2 encoding (or UTF-16 encoding if the current database is using an _SC supplementary character collation).

Comment: Thank you all bro,
I tryed N'你好', But  i get crash.     ;(

Comment: The function's param is char*, so I use std::string

Comment: It certainly needs nchar on the SQL Server side. What is the "crash" you get?

Comment: And what if you try to replace statement with prepared statement and try to execute it with parameter binding:`SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WVARCHAR, 0, 0, &wValue, 0, SQL_NTS)`?